# How can I play?

Tags: learning, rules, beginner, pieces

Can someone please just tell me how all of the pieces move? I always get the castles and the priests mixed up, but I know one of them makes an "L" or a backwards "L". Thank you for your underatanding.

Comment: If you just tried to Google you would find [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_of_chess). It was one of the first hits...

Comment: hahaha, this question is hilarious

Answer (score 2):

Just look into this link and you will understand how all the pieces move and also how moves such as castling, en passant and pawn promotion work. Also it is a great website to learn chess.

http://www.chess.com/learn-how-to-play-chess#howtomove